# RackPick agents based on parameter Delivery Date

Tags: anylogic

I have model, where I need to pickup agents using RackPick from PalletRack when the model time matches the agent parameter delivery date.

I have a parameter of type date, and I am generating random delivery dates (withing 30 days) using the following code addToDate(date(), DAY, random()*30);

I have a parameter called DeliveryDate, and on that date I want to RackPick agents from the pallete rack.

How can I do this?

Here are the images,

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How does your process flow look like? Is there an Enter block before your RackPick or do  you just put them in a wait block or something else? (It's best if you can share screenshots)

Comment: Screenshots are provided, please check

Comment: Thank you, but the exact logic is not clear to me yet. Is your source producing Order type agents and you want to pick the Order agent at DeliveryDate, or are you creating generic Agents in the source and want to pick OrderQuantity number of products from the pallet rack at DeliveryDate? (Or something different?)

Comment: I have a parameter called DeliveryDate, and on that date I want to RackPick agents from the pallete rack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: in AnyLogic parameters should start with a lowercase letter to avoid confusion with classes and agent types. I used the lowercase version of your parameters in my code snippets.*

I am going to assume you have generic Agent type agents in your pallet rack and on the date `deliveryDate` of an order you want to pick as many as the `orderQuantity` parameter describes.

Right now you are picking agents as soon as they were put into the pallet rack. To avoid this, put a Wait block between RackStore RackPick. Then create a Dynamic Event - I called it PickAgent. It will be responsible for freeing an agent from the wait block on delivery dates. PickAgent's action is `wait.free(wait.get(0))`.

[image: updated process flow]

In your orders population delete the default value of `deliveryDate` and go to your Order agent and write the following in the 'On startup:' action:

```java
double deliveryDays = random()*30;
deliveryDate = addToDate(date(), DAY, deliveryDays);
for (int i = 0; i<orderQuantity; i++){
    main.create_PickAgent(deliveryDays, DAY);
}
```

This will set the `deliveryDate` parameter of your Order and also create a number of PickAgent events equal to `orderQuantity` that will take action on `deliveryDate`. This will lead to `orderQuantity` number of agents to be picked from the pallet rack.

*Note 2: If your Wait block is empty, this will throw an error. You need to define what should happen when there are not enough agents in storage to fulfill an order.*